# Swift map empty string to nil

Tags: swift

I'm using an map function and must map an empty string to nil, otherwise the string. Problem is that the input is Any?

```
var arr : Any? = ["hallo", "", nil, "hihi"]
let res = arr.map{ (($0 ?? "") as! String).isEmpty ? nil : $0 }
print(res)
```

Do you know how to do this?

The map function is this here:

```
id <- (map["id"], TransformOf<Int, String>(fromJSON: { Int($0!) }, toJSON: { $0.map { String($0) } }))
```

https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#custom-transforms

Comment: Doesn't you want to ignore the nil object from array?

Comment: What is the result of the code you posted?

Comment: I think result should be ["hallo", nil, nil, "hihi"] @rmaddy

Comment: @netshark1000 you should consider using an array of Any?. This will map over the optional not the array which is an associated value of your optional.

Comment: @Cruz I know what output they want. I'm asking the OP what their current code is giving them at the moment or what exact problem they have with their code.

Comment: My problem is that the map function is given: id <- (map["id"], TransformOf<Int, String>(fromJSON: { Int($0!) }, toJSON: { $0.map { String($0) } })) https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper#custom-transforms

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```
var arr : Any? = ["hallo", "", nil, "hihi"]
if let array = arr as? [String?] {
    let result = array.map { ($0?.isEmpty ?? true) ? nil : $0 }
    print(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing an array is `Any?` is questionable, but if you must...

```
let arr: Any? = ["hallo", "", nil, "hihi"]

guard let casted = arr as? [String?] else {
    // handle error
    fatalError("arr is not a [String?]")
}

let result: [String?] = casted.map{
    guard let s = $0 else { return nil }
    return s.isEmpty ? nil : s
}

print(result as Any)
```